# Flow, how to inherit class function typings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I've made a simple router class that when simplified looks like this

```
// @flow
import { Container } from 'unstated'

type State = {
  history: Object[],
  pathname: string,
  data: Object | null
}

class RouterState extends Container<State> {
  state = {
    history: [{ pathname: '/onboarding/sign-in', data: null }],
    pathname: '/onboarding/sign-in',
    data: null
  }


  mutationPush = (pathname: string, data?: Object | null = null) => {
    if (pathname !== this.state.pathname) {
      const history = [...this.state.history, { pathname, data }]
      this.setState({
        history,
        pathname,
        data
      })
    }
  }
}
export default RouterState
```

Unfortunately `RouterState.mutationPush` does not return type because it is not a static function, which is expected due to usage of `extends Container` and how this is used in my React app. I am trying to figure out a way where I can export type of each individual function in class like this.

**Edit** specific use case for this would be

```
type Props = {
  push: RouterState.mutationPush
}
```

That errors with

> [flow] Cannot get `RouterState.mutationPush` because property `mutationPush` is missing in statics of `RouterState` [1].
>   (References: [1])
>       [Flow]
>       mutationPush: any

**Edit2**: I tried adding type exports in class so

```
export type mutationPush: (pathname: string, data?: ?Object) => void

/* ... */

mutationPush: mutationPush = (pathname, data) => ...
```

but wherever I use this function, flow helper says this `mutationPush: mutationPush` instead of `mutationPush: (pathname: string, data?: Object) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$PropertyType](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-propertytype) utility type to get the type of a property or method.

```
type Props = {
  push: $PropertyType<RouterState, 'mutationPush'>
}
```